# I need to loop this array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I use ajax to get a array from Economic and i would like to loop though it. The array (sortned):

```
    {   
  "collection": [  
    { "customerNumber": 1, "email": "jo+billing@test.com", "name": "Tester Test" }  
    , { "customerNumber": 2, "name": "Demo Name" }  
    ]  
    , "metaData": { "more array" }  
    , "pagination": { "more array"}  
    , "self": "some url"   
    }
```

The jquery I think I need to use but give me a error: (TypeError: cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in '{
    "collectio...')

```
  $.ajax({}).always(function (data) {  
        var options = $('#example').attr('options');  
        var substr = JSON.stringify(data, null, 4);  
//-----------loop part------------  
        $.each((substr), function(i, val1) {
            $.each(val1.customerNumber, function(a, val3) {  
                var CustInfo = val1[a]["name"] + " " + val1[a]["email"];  
                options[options.length] = new Option(CustInfo, val1[a]["customerNumber"]);  
            });  
        });  
    });
```

I am only interested in the values in "collection" and I want a select box with the customers info in it. like this:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">Tester Test jo+billing@test.com</option>
    <option value="2">Demo Name</option>
</select>
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify` - why are you turning this into a string? You want to iterate options.collection, not a string representation of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't have to use `JSON.stringify()` that will convert your response object `data` to a string that you can't loop through the attributes.

> I am only interested in the values in "collection".

Then no need for two loops just use the `data.collection` :

```
$.ajax({}).always(function (data) {  
    var options = $('#example').attr('options');

    $.each((data.collection), function(i, obj) {
        var CustInfo = obj["name"] + " " + obj["email"];  
        options[options.length] = new Option(CustInfo, obj["customerNumber"]);
    });  
});
```

```js
data = {
  "collection": [{
    "customerNumber": 1,
    "email": "jo+billing@test.com",
    "name": "Tester Test"
  }, {
    "customerNumber": 2,
    "name": "Demo Name"
  }],
  "metaData": [],
  "pagination": [],
  "self": "some url"
};

$.each((data.collection), function(i, val1) {
  var CustInfo = val1["name"] + " " + val1["email"];
  console.log(CustInfo, val1["customerNumber"]);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you this works. I was fixated on the need for two or tree loops that I lost my concentration and needed help.

Comment: Glad I could help bro.